# How to embed a text file into a single executable using py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a python script which reads a large dictionary file which is stored as a .txt file. Now I want to make a single executable using py2exe. Currently, my setup looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

Mydata_files = [('.', ['dict_lookup.txt'])]


setup(console=['BladeHost.pyw'],
  options = {
    "py2exe": {
        'bundle_files': 1, #with this == 1, I have the weird CreateActCtx error msg
        'compressed': True,
        "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll", "gdiplus.dll"],

        }
    },
  zipfile = None,
  data_files=Mydata_files,
  )
```

This setup gives me the executable and the dict_lookup.txt in the dist folder. However, I do not want this stupid .txt file outside of the executable. I know I copy and paste this text file into a long string inside the python script but that will make my python script ugly.

So my question is, is there a way to setup py2exe so that this .txt file is built into the executable?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Putting it into a Python file as a string is actually the way things are most often done. If you have a look at the [PyQt resource system](http://pythonxy.googlecode.com/hg-history/4ef4255f59b092a123a5788c821434d9fe94aee9/src/python/PyQt4/PLATLIB/PyQt4/doc/html/resources.html) for example, you will see that they embed any resource (images, sounds, etc...) as huge byte strings in some Python files that you should not modify afterwards.

Just make a separate Python file called `resources.py` or something like that if you want to keep your code clean. Then import the variables from that file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. There must be no better solutions to this. I'll follow your suggestion then.

Comment: There may be a solution with `py2exe`. But it would not be that simple anyway. For example, [have a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939883/py2exe-embed-static-files-in-exe-file-itself-and-access-them).

Comment: Thanks again. I used the Darren's solution in that thread and it worked out quite well. What a neat solution!